# I built custom add and subtract date function. but subtract date throws error for .getTime() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
const subtractDate = function(date1, date2){
    const date1Inms = date1.getTime()
    const date2Inms = date2.getTime()
    const subtract = new Date(date2Inms - date1Inms)
    return subtract
}

const addDate = function(date1, days){
    const date1Inms = date1.getTime()
    const dayInms = days*86400000
    const add = new Date(dayInms + date1Inms)
    return new Date(add)
}
```

my addDate function works correctly but I am getting error `"date1.getTime is not a function"` for subtractDate . I dont why ? I used getTime() in both but it throws error only in subtract function

Comment: my bad . There is no subtractDate anyways. what i need is timedelta as number of days. totally bad logic of writing function. sorry

Comment: the error was arising from string  that I was passing in function

Answer (score 3):

use this, should works.

```js
const subtractDate = (date1, date2) => new Date(date2.getTime() - date.getTime());
```